# How do I move an flexbox element to another line?

Tags: css, flexbox

The page has elements that are arranged in a row on the desktop. In the mobile version, one of the elements that is in the middle should be placed on a new line, how can flex do this?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  background: green;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  background: green;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .item:nth-child(2) {
    order: 3;
  }
  .item:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: calc(100% - 200px); /* 200px is width of 2 boxes */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```